# Get the image file path

Tags: c#, image, filenames

HI,

I am trying to retrive the filname of the image file from a file path in my code.

My filepath: c:\mydocuments\pictures\image.jpg

which method can i use in c# to get he filename of the above mentioned path.

Like String file = image.jpg

I have used the system.drawing to get he path, but it returns null.

my code:

```
string file = System.drawing.image.fromfile(filepath,true);
```

Is this the right way to get the image file name or is there any other inbuilt method in c#.

Pls help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

```
System.IO.FileInfo info = new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath);
string fileName = info.Name;
```

Comment: Should that not be info.FullName?

Comment: @uriDium: Nope, the OP asked for the filename without the path and in `FileInfo` you'll get it through the `Name` property.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Image.FromFile` returns an `Image` object, not the filename.

If you just want to get the filename portion of a path, use `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path)`